# How to initialize OverlayScrollbars script for a generic HTML page with unknown body height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I'm trying to use the [OverlayScrollbars script](https://kingsora.github.io/OverlayScrollbars/) on a basic HTML page that contains several paragraphs.

I want to apply this script to the `<body>` tag, the height of which is unknown to me in advance. How should I initialize the OverlayScrollbars script in this case? Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my current HTML structure:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>OverlayScrollbars Test</title>
    <style>
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
        -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
        box-sizing: content-box;
    }

    div,
    span,
    h1,
    h2,
    a,
    img,
    video {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
    }

    @media print {
        body {
            min-width: 1200px;
            max-width: 1200px;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border: none;
        }
    }

    .t-body {
        margin: 0;
        height: 100vh;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    #allrecords {
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        background-color: none;
    }

    .t-records {
        -webkit-font_smoothing: antialiased;
        background-color: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body class="t-body">
    <div id="allrecords" class="t-records">
        <!-- Several paragraphs here -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```